# .csv works fine, .tsv gives 'TypeError: expected string or buffer'

Tags: python, pandas, ua-parser

I'm working on a python script to parse user agent strings and reduce them down to just the 'family' (i.e., chrome, firefox, safari, etc).

I've got a script that works completely fine when run against csv files, but when I run the files against .tsv files it gives me the following error:

TypeError: expected string or buffer

Anyone else run across this problem? Sample code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob as glob
from ua_parser import user_agent_parser as uaparser

#THIS WORKS FINE:

def parse_uagent():
    ua_list = []
    uadf = pd.DataFrame()
    for datafile in glob.glob("*.csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(datafile, sep=',')
        df = df[['user_agent','date_time','user_name']]
        ua = df[df.columns[0]].values
    for line in ua:
        uagent = uaparser.ParseUserAgent(line)
        ua_list.append(uagent)
    uadf = uadf.append(ua_list)
    print uadf


#THIS GIVES AN ERROR:

def parse_uagent():
    ua_list = []
    uadf = pd.DataFrame()
    for datafile in glob.glob("*.tsv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(datafile, sep='\t')
        df = df[['user_agent','date_time','user_name']]
        ua = df[df.columns[0]].values
    for line in ua:
        uagent = uaparser.ParseUserAgent(line)
        ua_list.append(uagent)
    uadf = uadf.append(ua_list)
    print uadf
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-14c05dc8ee13> in <module>()
     29 
     30 
---> 31 parse_uagent()
     32 

<ipython-input-92-14c05dc8ee13> in parse_uagent()
     19         ua = df[df.columns[0]].values
     20     for line in ua:
---> 21         uagent = uaparser.ParseUserAgent(line)
     22         ua_list.append(uagent)
     23     uadf = uadf.append(ua_list)

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ua_parser/user_agent_parser.pyc in ParseUserAgent(user_agent_string, **jsParseBits)
    247     else:
    248         for uaParser in USER_AGENT_PARSERS:
--> 249             family, v1, v2, v3 = uaParser.Parse(user_agent_string)
    250             if family:
    251                 break

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ua_parser/user_agent_parser.pyc in Parse(self, user_agent_string)
     49     def Parse(self, user_agent_string):
     50         family, v1, v2, v3 = None, None, None, None
---> 51         match = self.user_agent_re.search(user_agent_string)
     52         if match:
     53             if self.family_replacement:

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Look at using pandas [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv)

Comment: I think the problem isn't with your code, but with the file you are passing to pandas, I have tried to read several _tsv_ files using the same code your provided and pandas just works fine with _Python 2.7_ and _Python 3.6.2_. Would you please show an example of the data you are passing?

Comment: Hi Andrew, the .tsv files i'm using _should_ be the same as the csv files, as the csv files were created by opening the tsv files in excel, selecting a sample of rows, and saving as csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.. the ua-parser was failing when it came across empty cells. Removing all lines with NaN prior to parsing fixed the error.